# how to guard a controller through multiple of user?

Tags: php, laravel-5.4, guard, laravel-middleware

It is project requirement. where i have multiple logins but some user can not access few module. like super admin and analyst   can access all module but developer can only use own controller.

so in this case , how can i guard a controller with multiple logins. also note that i have separate login page and table into Database.

for Example phonebookController can be access by super admin and analyst but  not by  developers.
so please tell me how can i implement this?

i use this for ::

```
if( Auth::guard('superAdmin')->check() )
 {   $author =Auth::guard('superAdmin')->User()->id ;  }
  else  if( Auth::guard('analysts')->check() )
 {   $author =Auth::guard('analysts')->User()->id;   }
 else
 {  $author =Auth::guard('supervisor')->User()->id    }
```

i want to use this into constructor method of class

Comment: log every access to controler to DB, and before every load of controller check if user can view of throw 403...

Comment: how are you assigning roles? is there a field in your user table which says if the user is admin or not?

Answer (score 2):

Here is my implementation for access control for admin and users(agents in my case)
I have a `boolean` field in my user table(`is_admin`) which is `0` for normal users and `1` for admins. so in my User model I did this

```
    protected $casts = [
        'is_admin' => 'boolean',
    ];

  public function isAdmin()
    {
            return $this->is_admin;
    }
```

Create a new middleware for the type of roles u want using

`php artisan make:middleware Admin`

`php artisan make:middleware Agent`

The middleware files will be created in App\Http\Middleware\
add this to class inside `Admin.php`

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{

    if ( Auth::check() && Auth::user()->isAdmin() )
    {
        return $next($request);
    }

    return redirect('/agent');

}
```

and this to `Agent.php`

```
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{

    if ( Auth::check() && !Auth::user()->isAdmin() )
    {
        return $next($request);
    }

    return redirect('/home');

}
```

After this register your middleware with laravel to do this add this to     `protected $routeMiddleware` in your Kernel.php which is located at `app\Http\Kernel.php`

```
'admin' => 'App\Http\Middleware\Admin',
'agent' => 'App\Http\Middleware\Agent',
```

make sure to create proper routes for redirection as we've mentioned in our middleware files.
after this you are almost done. Now to verify if a user is admin or normal user add this to the constructor method of your controller.

Actions allowed only for admin users

```
    public function __construct()
{   

    $this->middleware('auth');
    $this->middleware('admin');
}
```

Action allowed only for normal users

public function __construct()
{

```
$this->middleware('auth');
$this->middleware('agent');
```

}

Comment: public $user_type   ,   $participant_id  , $model_class , $model_type ;

    public function  __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware(function ($request, $next) {

            if( Auth::guard('analysts')->check() =='analysts' )
            {
                $this->  participant_id  = Auth::guard('analysts')->user()->id;
                $this -> user_type       = 'analyst';
                $this -> model_type      = 'Analyst';
                $this -> model_class     = 'App\Analysts';
            }         else
     {
          return redirect()->back();
            }

Comment: return $next($request);
        });
    }     $model = $this->model_class;

        $items = $model::where(  'id' , $this->participant_id  )->get()->first();

Comment: Good to know you solved it!. By the way you can use markdown in comments section too, ex. to format code enclose them in `back quotes`.