# Laravel 5.4 Middleware for Admin and User Role

Tags: php, laravel-5.4, laravel-middleware

I created two Middleware called "MustBeAdmin" and "MustBeUser" to make sure depending on the user login I redirect them to the right page and restrict unauthorized content. Currently everything is working fine and redirects work well too. But the Logic I wrote behind the scene seems wrong to me and its weird it still works.  If I write the logic that seems right to me atleast, it does not seem to work as expected.

## Users table

```
id (1,2,3,...)
name
role (1,2,3,...)
```

## Roles table

```
id (1,2,3,...)
role (Student, Admin,...)
```

## MustBeAdmin middleware

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if($request->user()->role == 2)
        {
            return $next($request);
        }
        else
        {
            return redirect('/admin/users');
        }

    }
```

## MustBeUser middleware:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    { 
        if($request->user()->role == 1)
        {
            return $next($request);
        }
        else
        {
            return redirect('/admin/users');
        }

    }
```

## kernel.php

```
'admin' => \App\Http\Middleware\MustBeAdmin::class,
'user' => \App\Http\Middleware\MustBeUser::class,
```

As you can see I have registered middlewares in kernel.

I am getting results exactly what I need but I doubt if the logic in middleware is correct?

```
1 = Student
2 = Admin
```

if you see in MustBeAdmin middleware I am comparing if user role is 2 (admin) then do next($request) and in MustBeUser middleware I am comparing if user role is 1 (Student) then do next($request) and I set else to /Admin directory.

I feel its wrong, what do you think?

Comment: Why are both redirecting to the same page? do you have a third entity  besides admin and user? Who will be redirected to admin/users?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are not checking the authenticated users details in your Middleware. The middleware should be something like:

```
//for student 
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{

    if ( Auth::check() && Auth::user()->role == 1 )
    {
        return $next($request);
    }

    return redirect('/admin');

}


//for admin 
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{

    if ( Auth::check() && Auth::user()->role == 2 )
    {
        return $next($request);
    }

    return redirect('/student');

}
```

You should check my detailed answer on the same topic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43558519/5045201)

Comment: If there are 5 roles.then shall I create 5 Middleware for handling it? Can it be managed in a common file?

Comment: @user3575353  I don't think it can be done in a single file, as you create a middleware using artisan and it by default creates a new file with name of your middleware

Answer (score 1):

Yes, It can be handled in one common file.
Here is the code

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $user = User::find(Auth::id());
    $roles = [];
    foreach ($user->roles as $key => $value) {
        array_push($roles, $value->pivot->role_id);
    }

    $routeName = Route::getFacadeRoot()->current()->uri();
    $route = explode('/', $routeName);
    if ($route[0] == "teacher") {
        if (in_array(2, $roles)) {
            return $next($request);
        } else {
            return response('Unauthorized.', 401);
        }
    } elseif ($route[0] == "student") {
        if (in_array(1, $roles)) {
            return $next($request);
        } else {
            return response('Unauthorized.', 401);
        }
    } elseif ($route[0] == "admin") {
        if (Auth::user()->admin == 1) {
            return $next($request);
        } else {
            return response('Unauthorized.', 401);
        }
    } else {
        if (!Auth::user()) {
            if ($request->ajax()) {
                    return response('Unauthorized.', 401);
            } else {
                    return redirect()->guest('admin-panel/auth/login');
            }
        }
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

You can alter the logic according to your need.